# Yarn start doesn't work with react-app-rewired

Tags: reactjs, npm, yarnpkg, antd

When I run yarn start, I get the following output

```
$ yarn start
yarn run v1.15.2
$ react-app-rewired start
The "injectBabelPlugin" helper has been deprecated as of v2.0. You can use customize-cra plugins in replacement - https://github.com/arackaf/customize-cra#available-plugins
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I tried reading the document at: https://github.com/arackaf/customize-cra#available-plugins but since I am new to React and npm, it didn't make much sense to me and I don't know which plugin to replace the deprecated helper with

my `config-overrides.js` looks like:

```
const { injectBabelPlugin } = require('react-app-rewired');
const rewireLess = require('react-app-rewire-less');

module.exports = function override(config, env) {
   config = injectBabelPlugin(['import', { libraryName: 'antd', style: true }], config);  // change importing css to less
   config = rewireLess.withLoaderOptions({
       modifyVars: {
           "@primary-color": "#1DA57A"
       },
   })(config, env);
    return config;
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do not use `injectBabelPlugin` this Pugin is deprecated

Use like this [enter link description here](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired/issues/348#issuecomment-452199363)

```
const {
  override,
  fixBabelImports,
  addLessLoader,
} = require("customize-cra");


module.exports = override(
  fixBabelImports("import", {
    libraryName: "antd", libraryDirectory: "es", style: true // change importing css to less
  }),
  addLessLoader({
    javascriptEnabled: true,
    modifyVars: { "@primary-color": "#1DA57A" }
  })
);
```